# Can "grow" be used in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> Surely, if one grows here, these years will without doubt be the best in their lives

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: "grows up" , if anything. I assume that you are speaking of children.

Comment: Yes its about kids and adults.

Answer (score 2):

In AmE, we usually say that plants grow (intransitive) or that someone grows them (transitive.)

However, when referring to children, we say they **grow up** (intransitive) or that their parents *raise* or *rear* them (transitive).

Here is an ngram chart for usage of these terms in British English:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raising+children%2Crearing+children%2Cbringing+up+children%2C+bringing+children+up&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craising%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crearing%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbringing%20up%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbringing%20children%20up%3B%2Cc0

And here is the same comparison for American English:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raising+children%2Crearing+children%2Cbringing+up+children%2Cbringing+children+up&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craising%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crearing%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbringing%20up%20children%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbringing%20children%20up%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In Britain whilst we *raise* and *rear* pigs, chickens, cattle, sheep (we even *raise* potatoes), we definitely **never** *raise* nor do we *rear* children. Children are *brought up*, and usually receive  their *upbringing* in the home of their parents.

Comment: Brian, thank you for the answer...Upbringing is the correct word.

Comment: Don't thank me, thank WS2.  "Bringing up" is used some in America as well, but "raising" and "rearing " are also common in written works. See my edited answer.